# Controllers in Grails

Tags: grails, controller, grails-orm

I'm writing a small webapp in Grails and I have the following question regarding best practices for controller design and using GORM:

I'm storing the user object in session.user. Currently all my action methods start with the following code to make sure a valid user is logged in and that the user object is fresh:

```
class FooController {
  def actionMethodThatRequiresAValidUser = {
    if (!session?.user) {
      redirect(controller: "authentication", action: "login")
    }
    session.user.refresh()
    ...
    /* do stuff */
    ...
  }
}
```

Is that best practice? Can it be done in a better and/or more concise way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a [filter](http://grails.org/doc/1.0.x/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.6%20Filters), that way you can put that same repeated code in the filter and keep your controllers focussed on the real action.

Comment: Doesn't filter introduce "hidden" code that is not immediately apparent to a developer that later reads the code?

Answer (score 3):

I think using beforeInterceptor is appropriate.And give some look at this [JSecurity plugin](http://grails.org/JSecurity+Plugin).For user authentication jsecurity plugin is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

You might try defining this as a [filter](http://grails.org/Filters) rather than [duplicating code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_duplication).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the filter suggestions others have made. If that doesn't work for you, you could define a [beforeInterceptor](http://grails.org/doc/1.0.x/ref/Controllers/beforeInterceptor.html) on your controller to minimize some duplication as well.

Answer (score 1):

Have you gone through [Spring Security Core](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core).
It's nice framework for security purpose..

Answer (score 1):

There is many ways
Better approach is use filter (before) and put 
if (!session?.user) {
      redirect(controller: "authentication", action: "login")
    }
this code in filter.

second thing you can use spring security plugin so that you don't have to worry about user session it will automatically control it.
see http://blog.springsource.org/2010/08/11/simplified-spring-security-with-grails/
for further information about plugin

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Spring Security Core Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core) which is a rich framework for security purposes. You can use the `springSecurityService.isLoggedin()` method after injecting the framework, but the framework provides for much finer access and privilege controls that also avoid the need for boilerplate.

Comment: I believe you have a start of a good answer.  Please consider developing it by having more supporting commentary and references.

Answer (score 1):

```
import grails.plugins.springsecurity.Secured
```

@Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_SUB_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER'])

class DashboardController{

def create() {

```
    [bankInstance: new Bank(params)]

}

def save() {
    def bankInstance = new Bank(params)
    if (!bankInstance.save(flush: true)) {
        render(view: "create", model: [bankInstance: bankInstance])
        return
    }

    flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'bank.label', default: 'Bank'), bankInstance.id])
    redirect(action: "show", id: bankInstance.id)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try [apache shiro plugin for grails](http://grails.org/plugin/shiro)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Spring Security Core](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core).... map Role of usages(User) in the System .. Configure the Same while Installing the Plugin... and dont forget to create an Admin user on bootstrap...

Comment: The question was related to best practises or doing it in a better way. Please elaborate on why it is a best practise/better way because of using `Spring Security Core`

Comment: Here are few advantages that I can think of on top of my mind:

1. Using Spring Security gives us the powerof a well tested code for security management. 

2. We get springSecurityService class which has many useful methods including getCurrentUser(). Thus, we do not need to do it ourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't looking for a completely secure answer, like Spring Security Core, you can use this code from the grails documentation as a filter:

```
class SecurityFilters {
   def filters = {
       loginCheck(controller:'*', action:'*') {
           before = {
              if(!session.user && !actionName.equals('login')) {
                  redirect(action:'login')
                  return false
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I second spring security. You are trying to reinvent the wheel here. All this has been done for you and more.